# Weird Apache Access Logs \x -Path

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm getting a lot of such requests, i was wondering what they are trying to hack or whether the system was compromized?!

```
80.137.206.13 - - [21/May/2013:15:59:38 +0200] "LW\x96\x92\xa5Fg\xa9\xa21\xb4/;\xb6\xef\x1e\xe6\x175l\xa9\x85\xa8\x91\x9c\x98V\x1e\r\xb1o\xd6L\x07\xc3\x9cv\xaaw\x8ak\xddw" 400 316 "-" "-"
84.176.243.124 - - [21/May/2013:16:02:37 +0200] "\x0fAy\xcb\x99|" 302 0 "-" "-"
68.34.99.222 - - [21/May/2013:16:03:46 +0200] "\x8ee\x88\xc1t\xe3\x84W\x89M\x12\xbf\xf0\x11\x84\x1e\x18" 302 0 "-" "-"
31.16.203.34 - - [21/May/2013:16:05:46 +0200] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
81.109.229.103 - - [21/May/2013:16:07:36 +0200] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
92.145.3.106 - - [21/May/2013:16:09:36 +0200] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
78.94.199.112 - - [21/May/2013:16:18:32 +0200] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
62.53.164.158 - - [21/May/2013:16:22:56 +0200] "J\xf2LY\x0e4\x18D\x0f\xc0\xa0\xef\xa2" 302 0 "-" "-"
85.67.38.79 - - [21/May/2013:16:35:46 +0200] "\x01\x85\xe4" 302 0 "-" "-"
79.236.201.21 - - [21/May/2013:16:51:12 +0200] "\xacd\x83" 302 0 "-" "-"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These appear to be unicode-encoded URI paths.

If you serve unicode-encoded URLs this sort of stuff in your logs is normal, otherwise it's possible someone is looking for a server with unicode-parsing vulnerabilities to exploit.
Beyond ensuring that your server is patched up to date no special action is required unless you see some evidence that your system has *actually* been compromised.

See [this other question](https://serverfault.com/questions/228109/what-exploit-is-this) for more information.

Comment: Presumably, it also indicates that the User Agent has not percent-encoded the path.